# how to retrieve an image from path in iOS ( for iPhone) with Flex

Tags: iphone, ios, flex-mobile

How can I retrieve the path of an image stored in my album in an iPhone using Flex mobile? same with an image being taken with the camera on the iPhone.

for Android I use this function and it works, but for the iPhone, it doesn't any ideas?

```
  protected function onMediaSelect(event:MediaEvent):void
            {
                var mp:MediaPromise = event.data;
                image.source = mp.file.url;
            }
```

and this I use for when I'm taking th picture ont he spot

```
protected function onComplete(evt:MediaEvent):void
            {
                img.source = evt.data.file.url;
            }
```

if you can show me in the right direction I greatly appreciate it. thanks!

~Myy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ad to use [the cameraroll class](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/media/CameraRoll.html)

```
//if we get the image
trace( "Asynchronous media promise." );
                    var eventSource:IEventDispatcher = dataSource as IEventDispatcher;            
                    eventSource.addEventListener( Event.COMPLETE, onMediaLoaded );
```

Answer (score 0):

image.source = File.desktopDirectory.resolvePath(file_name).url;

Answer (score 0):

```
this one it will work only under windows...



   image.source = File.desktopDirectory.resolvePath(file_name).nativePath;
```

the source property of Image passing a filename that start with / (/ is root for unix based OS, android, linux, ios, etc), will take is as a relative path instead of complete path...